# Mouse Over for Search Button?

Tags: css, mouseover

[On this page](http://glamourunderground.com), I'm trying to get the white 'search' text to turn pink when moused over - but right now, even the pointer isn't transforming into a hand icon on mouse over...

The search does work though.

Thanks for any suggestions,

Tara

```
#s {
  margin-left:0px;
  float: left;
  width:200px;
  height:13px;
  padding: 6px 2px 7px 5px;
  background:#f4f4f4;
  border:1px 0px 1px 1px #000;
  font: normal 100%  Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color:#333;
}

#s.hover {
  margin-left:0px;
  float: left;
  width:200px;
  height:13px;
  padding: 6px 2px 7px 5px;
  background:#f4f4f4;
  border:1px 0px 1px 1px #000;
  font: normal 100%  Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-color:#ff9999;
  color:#333;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that 'search' input submit text to become pink on mouseover (CSS `:hover`) and to show a hand cursor, you could write a rule for `#searchsubmit:hover` like:

```
#searchsubmit:hover{
    color:pink; /*or whatever*/
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need a *colon* instead of a period, so:

```
#s:hover {
    /* omitted */
}
```

Comment: You mean a colon. A semicolon looks like this: `;`.

Comment: #s is the input text, I think OP means the submit button with text 'search' (#searchsubmit)